# Term Structure of Corporate Bond

Tags: term-structure, credit-ratings

I am looking for some clarity on data for `Corporate Bond term structure` based on `Credit Rating`. Let say, I need to get the Term Structure for Corporate Bonds with rating `CCC`, how can I get such information in reality? There would be thousands of such Issuers so for every case I will get little different Term structure based on Liquidity and other factors?

How practitioners actually get such Term structure? Does `Bloomberg` provide such data directly for various Ratings??

Comment: Usual sources are indeed Bloomberg or Reuters. I do not know the Bloomberg Mnemonic, but Reuters screen **SECTORCURVES** and **ISSUERCURVES** can be a good starting point. Reuters (usually) has sector curves for Rating AAA/AA to BB /B available.

Comment: @Kermittfrog could you please share some schreenshots from Reuters

Comment: Sorry, I have no access to Reuters

Answer (score 1):

On Bloomberg: `CRVF` ("Curve Finder"), pick your country/region then tab 12 for credit. This will give you curves by sector and/or by ratings bucket, though only down to single B from what I can see.

Not something we use so I can't comment on the quality of the curves.

I'd guess some banks (e.g. BAML) have similar data/analytics.

Comment: Thanks. I dont have Bloomberg access at this moment. Can you please some screen-shots?

Comment: I can't post screenshots though I don't think they'd help - you asked for term structure for CCC but BBG only goes down to B from what I can see.